# Stop javascript firing when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm calling this function onload on the body using `<body onload="dis()">`

```
function dis(){
    if($('#stname').val() == ""){
        $('#update').hide();
        $('#newstore').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#update').show();
        $('#newstore').hide();
    }
}
```

Basically I want to check if a particular input box is empty or not on load. If it's empty, newstore button should show. If not, it should show the update button. But this way, it works as I want when page loads, but when I type something in the `stname`, the buttons switch. What's the way to counter this? Is there a way to stop the javascript firing when the page is finished loading?

Comment: try to call this function inside document.ready => $(document).ready(function() {  dis(); // call function here    });

Comment: please share your html code also. did you call this function on any textbox event like key up/down?

Comment: `<input type="text" name="stname" value="<?php echo $stname; ?>" id="stname" size="30" required >` no keyup/downs @JitendraTiwari

Comment: Problem is any other part of code. This script code will not fire more than one as per your provided code. May be this function will call any other place or same name function exist. Try to change function name once.

Comment: Ah! @JitendraTiwari, you caught me. I had called the function onchage() in the for. My bad, sorry guys

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is

```
$(window).on("load",function(){
    if($('#stname').val() == ""){
        $('#update').hide();
        $('#newstore').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#update').show();
        $('#newstore').hide();
    }
})
```

Comment: Then you need to hide both first.. add a css `display:none`

Comment: `<style>
 #update{
  display:none;
 }
 #newstore{
  display:none;
 }
 </style>`

Comment: Hid both, now nothing appears

Comment: Can you show us a fiddle? maybe we can help you there

Comment: I would suggest checking the length of `stname` to see if it is greater than zero, rather than `==`.

Answer (score 1):

Do the check when the document DOM is ready, which is easy to do since you are using JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('#stname').val() == ""){
        $('#update').hide();
        $('#newstore').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#update').show();
        $('#newstore').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: As a Jquery object yes :D Missed out the `$` sign at first :D

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to set the visibility on page load, you must change it when the content of your field is changed. You could use the "change" event on this field like

```
var field = $("#stname");

field.on("change", function() {
    $("#update").toggle(field.val() === "");
    $("#newstore").toggle(field.val() !== "");
});
```

The toggle() works like hide() and show() together, taking a boolean parameter to either show (true) or hide (false).

Answer (score 0):

you can use DOM inteand of body load .
A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included inside $( window ).load(function() { ... }) will run once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('#update').show();
   $('#newstore').hide();

  // run this if field empty
  if($('#stname').val() == ""){
      $('#update').hide();
      $('#newstore').show();
  }
```

});

for more https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 0):

To offer you an alternative solution you may not have considered: this can be achieved in CSS, without any JavaScript, using the [adjacent sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) & [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) selectors and the [negation pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not), assuming the `input` element shares the same immediate parent as the `button` elements, or their parent element, like so:

```
#stname[value=""]~[#parent ]#update,#stname:not([value=""])~[#parent ]#newstore{
    display:none;
}
```